# Recaptcha with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, recaptcha

I am trying to implement recaptcha my form in CodeIgniter (without using the recaptcha library). This works fine, however as in my form, I am displaying each fields errors individually, I want to display recaptcha error next to its place in the form, can someone help me how can i do it?

The code from my controller:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email address', 'trim|required|valid_email');   

    //With above set_rules i'm able to display each fields errors next to it, 
    //How can i display following recaptcha error next to it.
        if (!$resp->is_valid)
        {
            //reCAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
            die (
            "The reCAPTCHA wasn entered incorrectly." .
            "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")
            ");
        }
        else
        {
            //Successful verification
            die('Success!');
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't running the recaptcha field through the form validation library you won't be able to use the `form_error()` function, but you can easily send the error to your view as a variable:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    if ( ! $resp->is_valid)
    {
        $data['recaptcha_error'] = "reCAPTCHA said: ".$resp->error;
    }
    else
    {
        // Process form
    }
}
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

Then in your view (wherever/however you want):

```
<?php if (isset($recaptcha_error)): ?>
    <label class="error">
        <?php echo $recaptcha_error; ?>
    </label>
<?php endif; ?>
```